# Checking if user's e-mail address already exists in Kentico

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I am working with Kentico API and trying to check if an e-mail of a user does already exist within a website.

I tried the code below:

```
bool check =  IsEmailUnique(String, UserInfo)
```

I'm not sure what `UserInfo` object should be passed.

Comment: please show code of method IsEmailUnique

Answer (score 2):

This will check for an existing email address:

```
bool emailAlreadyExists = UserInfoProvider.IsEmailUnique(emailToCheck, MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);
```

Comment: How does this not provide an answer to the question @dbugger?  It is exactly what I would have posted.  The OP wants to know how to check if an email already exists in a site.  The code sample above provides a direct answer to that question.  Straight from [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):  "_Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better._".  Brief, to the point answer.

Comment: Two things: a) A fuller explanation would have been better.  b) "Can you try this" usually indicates the answerer is unsure of the answer and is offering a comment.

Answer (score 1):

UserInfo is whichever user you are trying to check.

`MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser` is the Current User UserInfo.

If you are trying to check prior to creating a user, or just can't access the userinfo any way you can search with something like this

```
UserInfo user = UserInfoProvider.GetUsers().Where("Email",QueryOperator.Equals,"test@test.com").FirstObject;
bool isUnique = user == null;
```

If user is null then there is no user with that email address.